# Reset Perspective in E4 Application(Using Snippets)and few parts contributed by other Fragments (fragment.e4xmi)

Tags: e4

I have to reset a Perspective in E4 application. EModelService.resetPerspectiveModel() method is not working.

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=404231

There was a work around which I found . Using EmodelService.CloneSnippet() Method which will create a dummy perspective and Switch to new Perspective. This works fine for Parts and Containers contributed by Application.e4xmi

But in my application, some parts for the perspective are contributed via different fragments(fragments.e4xmi). When i do reset perspectives, these parts are not visible in the perspective after reset.